# Must have apps for netbook running windows 7

Tags: windows-7, netbook

What are the must have apps for a netbook running windows 7? It's for a gift for my parents, so no ssh clients or vim etc.

Comment: Offtopic/Dupe - [Useful software for netbook?](http://superuser.com/questions/55364/useful-software-for-netbook)

Comment: What are your parents going to use it for? Seriously, this question is impossible to answer because it's too broad.

Comment: @Sathya: That question has answers for Linux. @Dennis: Normal usage - web browsing, email, IM, music, video, office etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Ninite][1] to create an all-in-one installer. Keeping in mind it's a netbook (light software), I recommend Chrome for web browsing, Thunderbird for mail, Foobar2000 for music, VLC for video, Picasa/Irfanview for pics, OpenOffice + Foxit Reader for docs. There are some basic tools also to be added on the Ninite page.

[1]: http://ninite.com/ Ninite

Answer (score 1):

Set up a free 2GB [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) account for them as a backup solution and for sharing photos and other files with family and friends.